# How to animate individual list items?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate each individual li list element while maintaining the list format.

Here is the css

```js
$(".BeverlyWarbrickcontent").css("visibility", "hidden");

$("#BeverlyWarbrick").mouseover(function() {
  $(".BeverlyWarbrickcontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#BeverlyWarbrick").mouseover(function() {
  $(".BeverlyWarbrickcontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#BeverlyWarbrick").mouseout(function() {
  $(".BeverlyWarbrickcontent").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});


$(".MargaretNooskicontent").css("visibility", "hidden");

$("#MargaretNooski").mouseover(function() {
  $(".MargaretNooskicontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#MargaretNooski").mouseover(function() {
  $(".MargaretNooskicontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#MargaretNooski").mouseout(function() {
  $(".MargaretNooskicontent").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});


$(".SavannahHallcontent").css("visibility", "hidden");

$("#SavannahHall").mouseover(function() {
  $(".SavannahHallcontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#SavannahHall").mouseover(function() {
  $(".SavannahHallcontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#SavannahHall").mouseout(function() {
  $(".SavannahHallcontent").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});



$(".TraciCliftoncontent").css("visibility", "hidden");

$("#TraciClifton").mouseover(function() {
  $(".TraciCliftoncontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#TraciClifton").mouseover(function() {
  $(".TraciCliftoncontent").css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$("#TraciClifton").mouseout(function() {
  $(".TraciCliftoncontent").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.women {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.women ul li {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#BeverlyWarbrick {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -o-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: float-right;
  -moz-animation-name: float-right;
  -o-animation-name: float-right;
  animation-name: float-right;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  left: -500px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes float-right {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {}
  80% {
    left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes float-right {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes float-right {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@-keyframes float-right {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}


}
.BeverlyWarbrickcontent h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}
.BeverlyWarbrickcontent p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#BeverlyWarbrick:hover .BeverlyWarbrickcontent {}
.MargaretNooskicontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.MargaretNooskicontent h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}
.MargaretNooskicontent p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.SavannahHallcontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.SavannahHallcontent h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}
.SavannahHallcontent p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.TraciCliftoncontent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.TraciCliftoncontent h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}
.TraciCliftoncontent p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.wrapperleft {
  width: 50vw;
  display: block;
}
.wrapperright {
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapperleft">
  <div class="women">

    <ul>
      <div id="BeverlyWarbrick">
        <li>Beverly Warbrick</li>
      </div>
      <div id="MargaretNooski">
        <li>Margaret Nooski</li>
      </div>
      <div id="SavannahHall">
        <li>Savannah Hall</li>
      </div>
      <li>Destiny Rae Tom</li>
      <li>Loren Donn Leslie</li>
      <li>Therese Umphrey</li>
      <li>Tracey Nadine Jack (Wolfe)</li>
      <li>Anita Florence Thorne</li>
      <li>Cynthia Frances Maas</li>
      <li>Doreen Jack</li>
      <li>Aielah Saric Auger</li>
      <li>Christine Kinequon</li>
      <li>Stephanie Joy Donnelly</li>
      <li>Roberta (Robin) Marie Sims</li>
      <li>Sheila Faye Kinequon</li>
      <li>Roxanne Thiara</li>
      <li>Lana Derrick</li>
      <li>Ramona Wilson</li>
      <li>Alishia 'Leah' Germaine</li>
      <li>Monica Ignas</li>
      <li>Roswitha Fuchsbichler</li>
      <li>Shirley Williams</li>
      <li>Coreen Thomas</li>
      <li>Jessica Patrick (Balczer)</li>
      <li>Maria Practicante Rego</li>
      <li>Brittany Giese</li>
      <li>Amanda Jean Simpson</li>
      <li>Tara Lee Ann Williams</li>
      <li>Kimberly Dumais</li>
      <li>Hazel White</li>
      <li>Nina Marie Joseph</li>
      <li>Nicole Hoar</li>
      <li>Immaculate ''Mackie Mary Basil</li>
      <li>Natasha Lynn Montgomery</li>
      <li>Emmalee Rose Mclean</li>
      <li>Kayla Rose McKay</li>
      <li>Monica McKay</li>
      <li>Maureen Sullivan</li>
      <li>Mary Madeline George</li>
      <li>Mary Jane Hill</li>
      <li>Madison "Maddy" Geraldine Scott</li>
      <li>Linda Geraldine Le Franc</li>
      <li>Linda Fredin</li>
      <li>Helen Claire Frost</li>
      <li>Tamara Lynn Chipman</li>
      <li>Marnie Blanchard</li>
      <li>Cynthia Martin</li>
      <li>Jean Mary Kovacs</li>
      <li>April Rose Johnson</li>
      <li>Helena Jack</li>
      <li>Unnamed</li>
      <li>Donna Charlie</li>
      <li>Jill Stacey Stuchenko</li>
      <li>Jean Virginia "Ginny" Sampare</li>
      <li>Frances Brown</li>
      <li>Melanie Dawn Brown</li>
      <li>Leah Marie Faulkner</li>
      <div id="TraciClifton">
        <li>Traci Clifton</li>
      </div>
      <li>Wendy Ann Twiss Ratte</li>
      <li>Helga Rochon</li>
      <li>Sherri Rochon</li>
      <li>Pauline Rochon</li>
      <li>Delphine Anne Camelia Nikal</li>
      <li>Cicilia Anne Nikal</li>
      <li>Chantelle Catherine Simpson</li>
      <li>Candace Marie Kalmokoff</li>
      <li>Chassidy Charlie</li>
      <li>Bonnie Marie Joseph</li>
      <li>Ada Elaine Brown</li>
      <li>Barbara Joseph</li>
      <li>Alberta Gail Williams</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapperright">

  <!--<img src="https://tce-live2.s3.amazonaws.com/media/media/2fd08a5f-bf5f-4b4c-988d-8455a418d99b.jpg"/>-->

  <div class="BeverlyWarbrickcontent">
    <h1>Beverly Warbrick</h1>
    <p>Went missing from the 2100 block of Oak Street in Prince George in June 2007.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="MargaretNooskicontent">
    <h1>Margaret Nooski</h1>
    <p>Age: 89<br>Last known location: Fraser Lake<br>Was last seen hitchhiking near Fraser Lake when she went missing on the afternoon of Saturday 2 October 2004. She was last seen near the Nautley Road turn-off on Highway 16. A helicopter searched for
      her on 5 October 2004. She was suffering from dementia and had difficulty walking. RCMP stated that they think she may have been trying to get to Prince George, or she may have headed into the bush in search of her traditional trapping territory.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="SavannahHallcontent">
    <h1>Savannah Hall</h1>
    <p>Age: 89<br>Last known location: Fraser Lake<br>Was found gurgling and gasping by foster parents Patricia and Thomas Keene in their Prince George home. A leather harness, the sort normally used to teach toddlers to walk, would be fastened to her chest
      and shoulders. Straps would then be tied to her crib, to keep her in place. A coroner's inquest was held which determined the cause of death was homicide.[72] No charges were ever laid. However the Keenes were taken off the Ministry of Children
      and Family Development's "preferred homes" list for foster care. Thomas Keene subsequently attempted to sue the BC government for "loss of profits" due to the loss of income his family received from foster care after being removed from preferred
      homes list (BC Civil Court file 14097/03)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="TraciCliftoncontent">
    <h1>Traci Clifton</h1>
    <p>Age: Unknown<br>Last known location: Prince Rupert<br> Exact date that Traci went missing is not yet public knowledge. It was reported at an inquiry for murdered and missing indigenous women as some time in the 1970s. She had an argument with her
      mom, left home and started walking highway 16 and was never seen again.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that it requires the div to be position: absolute which takes the item out of its list position.

Is there a way that I can animate each individual list item while maintaining their list positions?

You can see example here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mxrzmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `position: absolute;`, you need to use `position: relative;`

```
#BeverlyWarbrick {
   position: relative;
}
```

For example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.women {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.women ul li {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}

.women div {
  position: relative;
  animation: 2s float-right ease-out forwards;
  left: -500px;
}

.women div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes float-right {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="women">
  <ul>
    <div id="BeverlyWarbrick">
      <li>Beverly Warbrick</li>
    </div>
    <div id="MargaretNooski">
      <li>Margaret Nooski</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I've removed some code from the below snippet and have kept it at a minimal for the demo purpose only.

Moreover, the way you are writing your CSS is not scalable. You are repeating the same CSS for every element. Instead of that, consider using tag selectors, also, it is recommended to use SASS for such things so that you can easily loop the delays for each item to animate or you can use jQuery to append a `class` to each of these items with a delay and then animate them one after the other.

---

After your comment, I've added a jQuery solution as well to delay each of these items. For example:

```js
let c = 0;
$(".women").find('div').each(function() {
  let elm = $(this);
  elm.css({
    'animation-delay': `${c}s`
  });

  c++;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.women {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.women ul li {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}

.women div {
  position: relative;
  animation: 2s float-right ease-out forwards;
  left: -500px;
}

@keyframes float-right {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    left: -20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="women">
  <ul>
    <div id="BeverlyWarbrick">
      <li>Beverly Warbrick</li>
    </div>
    <div id="MargaretNooski">
      <li>Margaret Nooski</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here, am looping through all the `div` and adding a delay of `1s` over the previous `div` so these items will animate one after the other. Note that I've removed `animation-delay` for the 2nd `div` from CSS, unlike I had it in the previous solution because now you don't need that anymore.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your help. I am unfamiliar with jquery, do you have any examples of appending a class in order to animate them one after another?

Comment: @Sasha.Burger added a jQuery solution